# Why is there a Black Disturbance in my intro video that covers the middle?

Tags: video

I downloaded a intro template for blender from YouTube and followed instructions to render this intro. It rendered and after it was converted it showed up with a black rectangle all over the middle of the screen. Can someone please show me how to fix this issue? Yes, I'm a noob first time using blender.

Unlisted Video Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRGPXxqSGuU

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE!  Would it be possible to link to or [upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) the .blend file?  As it is it's practically impossible to tell what's wrong.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/yedl3405dc4r494/By+RiseFX.blend, here is the link that I used to make the intro. I realize that the same "thing" has been happening for everything. Thanks for replying.